# Can transloco.config.js in a monorepo environment support multiple apps built from different libraries

Tags: transloco

With reference to the structure explained in https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/tools/scope-lib-extractor, if we have two apps

1. app (built on core library)
2. app2[built on core2 library)

What is the best way to get translations from library included to respective consumer app ?
Scoped Library Extractor doesn't seem to support multiple configuration

```
module.exports = {
  rootTranslationsPath: './src/app/assets/i18n/',
  langs: ['en', 'es'],
  scopedLibs: ['./projects/core/']
};
```

```
module.exports = {
  rootTranslationsPath: './src/app2/assets/i18n/',
  langs: ['en', 'es'],
  scopedLibs: ['./projects/core2/']
};
```